# How to find whether there is a contradiction in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory, directed-graphs

I have a historical record that indicates the relative order of births and deaths. The format of these records are always in one of the following

- Person A was alive with Person B
- Person B died before Person A was born

For example

```
A was alive with B
C died before B was born
E died before D was born
E died before B was born
D was alive with B
D died before F was born
A was alive with E
F died before G was born
G died before D was born
A died before G was born
G was alive with C
```

yield this network:

[image]

We can see that there is a contradiction because `D<F<G` but `D>G`. More generally, what should I be looking for to find whether there is a an inconsistency in the graph? I can sort of understand how to do it with inequalities `D<F<G<D` which yields a cycle, but am more confused how to logically fuse in the equalities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is more convenient to represent each person $A$ by two vertices: their time of birth $A_b$, and their time of death $A_d$. Then, add an edge $u \to v$ whenever vertex $u$ is known to come before vertex $v$ chronologically:

- Initially, we add all edges of the form $A_b \to A_d$.
- Whenever $A$ and $B$ are alive at the same time, we add the edges $A_b \to B_d$ and $B_b \to A_d$.
- Whenever $A$ dies before $B$ is born, we add the edge $A_d \to B_b$.

In the actual (but unknown) timeline, these vertices are ordered (from earliest event to latest event) such that whenever $u \to v$, $u$ occurs before $v$. This is a [topological ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the directed graph we got. If there are no cycles in the directed graph, then at least one topological ordering exists: at least one timeline consistent with all the facts we have.

As mentioned in the Wikipedia article I linked to above, there are fast algorithms that will either

- find a topological ordering of the directed graph, in which case there is no contradiction, or
- find a directed cycle in the graph, in which case there is a contradiction.

Comment: Representing a person by two vertices was a clever idea. For anyone interested, here is an implementation that iterates off this (python): https://gist.github.com/MaksimDan/7176b6457ee6c6811d67e2beff8b01a0

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** If, as mentioned in comments, you want the "lived at the same time" relationship to be treated as an equivalence relation, contrary to all intuition, then you can just take a directed graph. $G,$ with nodes being the equivalence classes of people under this relationship, and edge $(x,y)$ when some person in the class $x$ lived strictly before some person in the class $y.$

Then the question is whether there is any loop in $G.$ This has a [simple algorithm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Detect-Cycle-in-a-Directed-Graph).

---

**Original Answer**

Not sure if this is the ideal approach, but if there are $n$ people define an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with $$A_{ij}=\begin{cases}1&i\text{ died before birth of }j\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then compute $$B=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda^iA^i=A(I-\lambda A)^{-1}.$$
We can do this for some $\lambda>0$ small. Then find any $B_{ij}\neq 0$ with $i,j$ Where persons $i,j$ lived in the same time (including all cases where $i=j.$) If there is such a $B_{ij},$ there is a contradiction.

Not sure if there is an efficient way to do this. You need $\lambda^{-1}$ to be greater than the absolute values of all eigenvalues of $A,$ but there might be an algebraic way to avoid picking a specific $\lambda.$

Comment: How do eigenvalues fit here? Would this work in the case there is a contraction from an equality that seem to be ignored? For example `A=B=C=D=E`, `A<C`, `C<E`, and `A=E`

Comment: No idea what you mean by “there is a contraction from an equality.” Here, you need $\lambda^nA^n\to 0$ which only happens for $\lambda^{-1}$ bigger than all the eigenvalues.

Comment: I would not use $A=B=C$ here, because if $A$ lived during the time of $B$ and $B$ during the time of $C,$ then it is not true that $A$ lived during the time of $C.$ My grandmother lived during the time of me and during the time of her grandmother, but I didn’t live in the time of my grandmother’s grand mother.

Comment: That is true in the realistic sense, but I am trying to be abstract here and generalize outside the context of the problem.

Comment: Then don’t pick a real-world example where it isn’t true. If you want something abstract, make it abstract. Don’t give a real world phrasing which doesn’t match your expected abstraction.

Comment: Anyway, you can do a similar matrix power series thing to find the complete $=$ relationship, if it is transitive.